# SQLAlchemy - Expression for hybrid property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a job and a task model where a job has several tasks, each of these tasks has a status. The Job is finished when the status of the latest task (by timestamp) has a status of `done`. All earlier statuses in the task list do not matter from the perspective of the job.

```
class Job(Base):
    __tablename__ = "job"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tasks = relationship("Task", order_by="desc(Task.created)", back_populates="job")

class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = "task"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    created = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())

    job_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("job.id"), nullable=False)
    job = relationship("Job", back_populates="task")
```

I added a `hybrid property` to the Job model to give it its own status based on the status of the first task item:

```
@hybrid_property
def status(self):
    if self.tasks:
        return self.tasks[0].status
    else:
        return None
```

This works when I query the model and look at the computed status:

```
>> job = session.query(Job).first()
>> job.status  # 4 (pending)
```

When I reference it on the class level (`Job.status`) , however, it doesn't work. I get a `NotImplementedError: <built-in function getitem>`. I think that I also need to define the `@status.expression` on the Job model but I haven't managed to do that so far and I can't find any good examples, neither in the docs nor in other places. I'd be super grateful for any pointers here.

*Side note:* It would be even nicer to have the `Job.status` computed by taking the latest timestamp into account (instead of only grabbing the topmost item in the `Job.tasks` list. But I guess this is not strictly necessary since the tasks are sorted by timestamp with `order_by="desc(Task.created)"`.

Comment: In which way are you using `Job.status`? Please add this to your question. It looks like it's only bound to the class and not to a specific Job.

Comment: The actual context is a bit involved to be laid out here in detail. Basically, I'm using a filter which needs a mapping of properties on the model. The mapping is a dictionary  of the form: `{status: Job.status}` and gets passed to the filter function. But I can reproduce the error by simply doing: `session.query(Job.status).all()` in an interactive session. It works for all real properties but not on the hybrid property.